# Android AES Encryption error during decrypting

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I know nothing about AES encryption in Android/Java

I got this code from here http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings

and I am getting the below error when it is getting decrypted whether there is some problem with my code?(I am passing the encrypted value from one activity to another)

```
 05-18 13:49:58.828: W/System.err(3350): javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block   corrupted
 05-18 13:49:59.133: W/System.err(3350):    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(JCEBlockCipher.java:653)
 05-18 13:49:59.148: W/System.err(3350):    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1116)
 05-18 13:49:59.153: W/System.err(3350):    at com.spacenext.noserver2.SimpleCrypto.decrypt(SimpleCrypto.java:55)
 05-18 13:49:59.158: W/System.err(3350):    at com.spacenext.noserver2.SimpleCrypto.decrypt(SimpleCrypto.java:28)
```

Encryption

```
 05-18 15:07:32.283: I/Home(3341): 530AEA4983C93379EB512387B4E547522C1E310AD6E7752AF5B9F91C329D313315FDDA853E60C78EA618211A37BA8A47
```

Encryption message received at another activity

```
 05-18 15:07:55.382: I/Home(7871): 530AEA4983C93379EB512387B4E547522C1E310AD6E7752AF5B9F91C329D313315FDDA853E60C78EA618211A37BA8A47
```

Both are same but when the message is decrypted at another activity it throwns an error message..

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868776/badpaddingexception-pad-block-corrupted and check the iv parameter

Comment: That code is just terrible and contains all kinds of gotchas that can rear up and bite you at any time. Whether it is one those gotchas that is causing your problem or something you are doing is impossible to tell with the info you have provided.

Comment: GregS The code works perfectly fine when the message is sent from same phone to phone but it doesn't work when it's sent from one to another

Answer (score 1):

This code uses a weak key derivation procedure, consider using standard password based encryption to derive your key.

The cause of your error is most probably that you are using the wrong key for decryption. Print it out in hex form and compare to your encryption key (output of `getRawKey()`). If you customized the code somehow, show relevant parts. How are you passing the encrypted value? Is it somehow encoded? Also check that the size is as expected in the decrypting activity.

Since encryption and decryption are done on different devices, and there is a server involved. here are a few more things to check/keep in mind:

1. Make sure that the cipher text you send from device A is what is received on device B. There might be encoding issues involved.
2. Don't use the default parameters for mode and padding. Those might different across your devices. Specify them explicitly like so `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")`
3. Make sure you send the IV along with the cipher text. Otherwise a random one might be generated automatically, and you won't be able to decrypt.

Comment: I am passing the encrypted value without being encoded and in the logs also it's the same and I use the same key for decryption and I didn't modify any of the above code.

Encryption is done on one activity
Decryption is done on another activity

Comment: Then the problems might indeed be with the initialization vector (IV) which is probably being generated randomly. Call `getIV()` on the encrypting `Cipher` or explicitly specify one. You can find some sample code here: http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2012/04/using-password-based-encryption-on.html

Comment: Still there is problem because I am sending these text from a phone to server and from server to phone? So whether this is the root cause of the problems?

Comment: And the android phones are of different version one is 2.2 and another one is 2.3?

Comment: Not the root problem, but might be a factor. See updated answer.

Comment: 1.I get the same text there also no issues