# Android AES encryption/decryption pad lock corrupted

Tags: android, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

I know that when you first look on the title you said that it had been asked a hundred time before.
But no this is different, at least the way I coded this.
I used this [code](https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2014/09/04/securely-store-user-credentials/) to encrypt/decrypt my data.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESHelper {
public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
    return toHex(result);
}

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
    return new String(result);
}

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}

private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted)
        throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}

public static String toHex(String txt) {
    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
}

public static String fromHex(String hex) {
    return new String(toByte(hex));
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length() / 2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2),
                16).byteValue();
    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
}

}
```

Actually, Encryption goes so fine. My problem goes with the decryption that returns **BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted**.
I am so new to this whole security thing and I really hope you could help.
Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868776/badpaddingexception-pad-block-corrupted)

Comment: Your main problem is copying code from random sources without having any idea what it does. The code you reference is a *poor* example, making poor and improper use of defaults and using the key derivation anti-pattern that misuses SecureRandom. For your specific problem you need to provide the inputs that cause the error to occur.

Comment: This is terrible code and should never be used. It is terrible because it only works on some JVMs. Not all JVMs are created equal and certainly not Android versions. In addition to what James said, you're better off using an established library like [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/JNCryptor) or [this](https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto).

Comment: On Android `getRawKey` actually creates a *fully random* key. And a random AES key is considered unbreakable. That said, your data is secure. Forever.

Comment: Thanks guys for your support and help. I will have a look at the libraries Artjom posted and try to refactor my code. :) If you have any reference for me to well-understand this security thing I'd be grateful If you post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is something I faced, that had brought me here. However after going through the comment section and no probable solution that suit what I was having and which was same as yours but from dart/flutter. I went back to my code, debugging and I later noticed that the argument supplied to both functions are different. This is what is throwing the error "pad lock corrupted".

so inspect the argument in encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) &  decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) and ensure that are case-sensitive and of same length.

Thanks.